# How do I turn off electric-indent mode within 'Fundamental' mode?

Tags: init-file, indentation, major-mode

Currently, in my `.emacs.d/init.el`, I have:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)

(push (cons "\\*shell\\*" display-buffer--same-window-action) display-buffer-alist)

(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode)
  (electric-indent-mode -1))
```

The last line does what I like, but it also turns it off in C mode, where I prefer it to be on. How can I make it so it's only off in fundamental mode, when I'm editing `.txt` or `.md` files or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `electric-indent-mode` does not provide an exclusion list where you could add `fundamental-mode` and `txt-mode`.

Use `electric-indent-local-mode` in major mode hooks instead of the global `electric-indent-mode`.

---

The first "normal" approach is to switch the minor-mode actively on in all major-modes you want it to have: Call `electric-indent-local-mode` in the hooks of the major modes where you want to switch it on:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'electric
  (electric-indent-mode -1))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'electric-indent-local-mode)
```

Alternative to `c-mode-hook` you can also use `prog-mode-hook` to switch `electric-indent-mode` on in almost all modes for programming languages.

---

The second version is to call `electric-indent-local-mode` in `after-change-major-mode-hook` if the major-mode is not in some exclusion list.

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'electric
  (electric-indent-mode -1))

(defcustom my-electric-indent-exclusion-list '(txt-mode fundamental-mode)
  "Major modes where `electric-indent-local-mode' is not switched on."
  :group 'my
  :type '(repeat symbol))

(defun my-switch-on-electric-indent ()
  "Maybe switch on `electric-indent-local-mode'.
Do not activate electric indent if the major mode is
in `my-electric-indent-exclusion-list'."
  (unless (apply #'derived-mode-p my-electric-indent-exclusion-list)
    (electric-indent-local-mode)))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'my-switch-on-electric-indent)
```

---

As Drew indicated in [his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76938/how-do-i-turn-off-electric-indent-mode-within-fundamental-mode/76939?noredirect=1#comment127754_76939), if it was not for fundamental mode, there would be another simple method to disable `electric-indent-mode` for specific major modes.

For most minor modes that have a global and a local version and where there is not an explicite exclusion list, it is possible to switch on the global version and switch it off with the local minor mode version in the major-modes hook.

This cannot be used for `fundamental-mode` since there is no `fundamental-mode-hook` variable.

I demonstrate it here for `text-mode`:

```el
(electric-indent-mode)

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 
      (lambda ()
        (electric-indent-local-mode -1)))
```

Comment: Good answer. Maybe worth pointing out that there's no mode hook for `fundamental-mode`. (If there were, then there would be a simpler answer.)

Comment: I realized that the third line in my `init.el` was what was causing the behavior I did not like. Regardless, you put a lot of thought and effort, and your answer worked with that line included. I'd like to note that `prog-mode` instead of `c-mode-hook` did not. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user129393192 Sorry, the statement about `prog-mode` was not very clear. I meant that you need to replace `c-mode-hook` with the hook for `prog-mode` which is `prog-mode-hook`. I just tried and `electric-indent-local-mode` in `prog-mode-hook` really turns on `electric-indent-mode` in `c-mode`. I modified the relevant sentence. Now it should be crystal clear.

Comment: @Drew You wrote: "Maybe worth pointing out that there's no mode hook for fundamental-mode. (If there were, then there would be a simpler answer.)". Do you mean the method that I added now to the answer? Thanks for the comment. I think that last bit completes the answer. BTW, IMHO global minor modes should provide exclusion lists for their users. Something that is easy to customize.

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, that's what I meant. And yes, some way of specifying excluded modes would be good. Maybe submit an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.